# Geoserver - Can't get LegendGraphic of WMS in Cascade

Tags: geoserver, style

I have configured a Cascade WMS in Geoserver and published some layers of this server. The Styles are shown correctly in Client Side Openlayers. But when I look at the capabilities no Online Resource is generated, so I can't get the legend URL.
Also there's no menu for styles when I try to edit those layers.

Why Openlayers is rendering the layers with the correct style if there's no style in my geoserver and the GetMap request has no style key?

```
http://192.168.1.14:8080/geoserver/jahr/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&tiled=true&LAYERS=jahr%3ACentros_Municipales&STYLES&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&SRS=EPSG%3A4258&BBOX=-0.4625%2C39.42875%2C-0.43125%2C39.46
```

Someone had the same problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The GeoServer documentation about cascaded WMS services http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/cascaded/wms.html has a section "Limitations"

Layers served through an external WMS have some, but not all of the functionality of a local WMS.

- Layers cannot be styled with SLD.
- Alternate (local) styles cannot be used.
- Extra request parameters (time, elevation, cql_filter, etc.) cannot be used.
- GetLegendGraphic requests aren’t supported.
- Image format cannot be specified. GeoServer will attempt to request PNG images, and if that fails will use the remote server’s default image format.
- Authentication for the remote WMS isn’t supported. The remote WMS must be unsecured. (*This part of documentation is old, you can give username/password of the remote WMS in the connection details*)

You asked three questions:

1. Q: Why not GetLegendGraphics link? A: It is not supported.
2. Q: Why I can't set local styles? A: It is not supported
3. Q: Why WMS shows correct styles even I have not set any? A: The default style of the remote WMS layer is used.